# need clarification about crontab on openshift scaleable application

Tags: openshift, cron, scalability

I have an openshift scaleable app comprised of JBOSS running with a MySql database. Suppose I schedule an hourly task, and when the time comes for that to run, I have 5 instances of my app running. Will all 5 instances run the crontab job, or only one? And if only one, will it always be the same one, or will I not know ahead of time which one?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a cron job setup on a scaled application, it will run on every web gear that is running at that time.

Comment: Thanks, @developercorey. That is what I was afraid of. Is there a standard way so that only one will run?